writing test for the upload image and get image methods in spring boot
I am working on a Spring Boot project. One of the features of the project is the ability to upload image and get image using APIs.
this is my UserServiceImpl:
package com.example.firsttask.service.impl;

import com.example.firsttask.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.firsttask.dto.UserResponse;
import com.example.firsttask.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.example.firsttask.model.Department;
import com.example.firsttask.model.Role;
import com.example.firsttask.model.User;
import com.example.firsttask.repository.DepartmentRepository;
import com.example.firsttask.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.firsttask.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.firsttask.service.UserService;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.example.firsttask.constant.Constant.IMAGE_DIRECTORY;

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    @Override
    public UserResponse saveUser(UserDto userDto) {
        User user = User.builder()
                .userId(userDto.getUserId())
                .firstName(userDto.getFirstName())
                .lastName(userDto.getLastName())
                .image(userDto.getImage())
                .department(unwrapDepartment(departmentRepository.findById(userDto.getDepartmentId()), userDto.getDepartmentId()))
                .role(unwrapRole(roleRepository.findById(userDto.getRoleId()), userDto.getRoleId()))
                .build();
        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);
        return userMapper.toUserResponse(savedUser);
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<UserResponse> getUserById(Long id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findById(id)
                .map(userMapper::toUserResponse)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException(id + " not found.")));
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserResponse> getAllUsers() {
        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();
        if (userList.isEmpty()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No Users!");
        return userList.stream().map(userMapper::toUserResponse).toList();
    }

    @Override
    public String uploadImage(Long id, MultipartFile multipartFile) {
        return userRepository.findById(id)
                .map(user -> {
                    String imageUrl;
                    imageUrl = saveImage(id, multipartFile);
                    user.setImage(imageUrl);
                    userRepository.save(user);
                    return imageUrl;
                }).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("User Not Found."));
    }

    private String saveImage(Long id, MultipartFile image) {
        String fileExtension = StringUtils.getFilenameExtension(image.getOriginalFilename());
        String fileName = id + "." + Optional.ofNullable(fileExtension).orElseThrow();
        try {
            Path fileStorageLocation = Paths.get(IMAGE_DIRECTORY).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
            Files.createDirectories(fileStorageLocation);
            Path targetLocation = fileStorageLocation.resolve(fileName);
            Files.copy(image.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            return "/api/v1/image/" + fileName;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to save image.");
        }
    }

    private static Department unwrapDepartment(Optional<Department> entity, Long departmentId) {
        if (entity.isPresent()) return entity.get();
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Department does not exist: " + departmentId);
    }

    private static Role unwrapRole(Optional<Role> entity, Long roleId) {
        if (entity.isPresent()) return entity.get();
        else throw new IllegalArgumentException("Role does not exist: " + roleId);
    }

}

and this is my UserController class:
package com.example.firsttask.controller;

import com.example.firsttask.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.firsttask.service.UserService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.example.firsttask.MotherObject.anyValidUserResponse;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    void testSaveUserSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode201Created() throws Exception {
        when(userService.saveUser(any(UserDto.class))).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/user/save")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(anyValidUserResponse()))
                )
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }

    @Test
    void testGetUserByIdSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getUserById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidUserResponse()));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/user/1")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testGetAllUsersSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getAllUsers()).thenReturn(List.of(anyValidUserResponse()));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/user/all")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testUploadImageSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test", "test.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));

        when(userService.uploadImage(1L, multipartFile)).thenReturn("/api/v1/image/test.jpg");

        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/api/v1/image/test.jpg")
                        .file(multipartFile)
                        .param("id", "1")
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testGetImageSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getUserById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidUserResponse()));
        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("image", "test.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/image/test.jpg")
                        .param("id", "123")
                        .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}

I want to write test for the uploadImage and getImage in the UserController and write unit test for my saveImage method in the UserServiceImpl class to cover the catch block.
my UserServiceTest:
package com.example.firsttask.service;

import com.example.firsttask.dto.UserResponse;
import com.example.firsttask.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.example.firsttask.model.User;
import com.example.firsttask.repository.DepartmentRepository;
import com.example.firsttask.repository.RoleRepository;
import com.example.firsttask.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.firsttask.service.impl.UserServiceImpl;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.example.firsttask.MotherObject.*;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
class UserServiceTest {

    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Mock
    DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    @Mock
    RoleRepository roleRepository;

    @Mock
    UserMapper userMapper;

    @InjectMocks
    UserServiceImpl userService;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testSaveUser_WhenProvidedDataIsCorrect_ThenReturnTheUser")
    void testSaveUserWhenProvidedDataIsCorrectThenReturnTheUser() {
        when(departmentRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidDepartment()));
        when(roleRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidRole()));
        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(anyValidUser());
        when(userMapper.toUserResponse(anyValidUser())).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        UserResponse userResponse = userService.saveUser(anyValidUserDto());

        assertThat(userResponse.getUserId()).isPositive();
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponse.getFirstName());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponse.getLastName());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponse.getImage());

        verify(departmentRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(roleRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).save(any(User.class));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testSaveUser_WhenDepartmentDoesNotExist_ThenCannotSaveTheUser")
    void testSaveUserWhenDepartmentDoesNotExistThenCannotSaveTheUser() {
        when(departmentRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        when(roleRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidRole()));
        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(anyValidUser());
        when(userMapper.toUserResponse(anyValidUser())).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> userService.saveUser(anyValidUserDto()));

        assertEquals("Department does not exist: 123", exception.getMessage());
        verify(departmentRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(roleRepository, never()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(userRepository, never()).save(any(User.class));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testSaveUser_WhenRoleDoesNotExist_ThenCannotSaveTheUser")
    void testSaveUserWhenRoleDoesNotExistThenCannotSaveTheUser() {
        when(departmentRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidDepartment()));
        when(roleRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(anyValidUser());
        when(userMapper.toUserResponse(anyValidUser())).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> userService.saveUser(anyValidUserDto()));

        assertEquals("Role does not exist: 123", exception.getMessage());
        verify(departmentRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(roleRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(userRepository, never()).save(any(User.class));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testGetUserById_WhenUserExists_ThenReturnTheUser")
    void testGetUserByIdWhenUserExistsThenReturnTheUser() {
        when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidUser()));
        when(userMapper.toUserResponse(anyValidUser())).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        UserResponse userResponse = userService.getUserById(123L).orElseThrow();

        assertThat(userResponse.getUserId()).isPositive();
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponse.getFirstName());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponse.getLastName());

        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testGetUserById_WhenUserDoesNotExist_ThenThrowAnException")
    void testGetUserByIdWhenUserDoesNotExistThenThrowAnException() {
        when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        when(userMapper.toUserResponse(anyValidUser())).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> userService.getUserById(12L));

        assertEquals("12 not found.", exception.getMessage());
        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testGetAllUsers_WhenUserExists_ThenReturnListOfUsers")
    void testGetAllUsersWhenUserExistsThenReturnListOfUsers() {
        when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(List.of(anyValidUser(), anyValidUser()));
        when(userMapper.toUserResponse(anyValidUser())).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        List<UserResponse> userResponseList = userService.getAllUsers();

        assertEquals("anyString", userResponseList.get(0).getFirstName());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponseList.get(userResponseList.size() - 1).getFirstName());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponseList.get(0).getLastName());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponseList.get(userResponseList.size() - 1).getLastName());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponseList.get(0).getImage());
        assertEquals("anyString", userResponseList.get(userResponseList.size() - 1).getImage());

        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).findAll();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testGetAllUsers_WhenListIsEmpty_ThenReturnEmptyList")
    void testGetAllUsersWhenListIsEmptyThenReturnEmptyList() {
        when(userRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(Collections.emptyList());
        when(userMapper.toUserResponse(anyValidUser())).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> userService.getAllUsers());

        assertEquals("No Users!", exception.getMessage());
        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).findAll();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testUploadImage_WhenTheUserExists_ThenUploadsTheImages")
    void testUploadImageWhenTheUserExistsThenUploadsTheImages() throws IOException {
        when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidUser()));
        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(anyValidUser());

        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("image", "test.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));

        String result = userService.uploadImage(1L, multipartFile);

        assertEquals("/api/v1/image/1.jpg", result);
        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).save(any(User.class));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testUploadImage_WhenUserDoesNotExist_ThenThrowsAnException")
    void testUploadImageWhenUserDoesNotExistThenThrowsAnException() throws IOException {
        when(userRepository.findById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.empty());
        when(userRepository.save(any(User.class))).thenReturn(anyValidUser());

        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("image", "test.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));

        IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () ->
                userService.uploadImage(1L, multipartFile));

        assertEquals("User Not Found.", exception.getMessage());
        verify(userRepository, atLeastOnce()).findById(anyLong());
        verify(userRepository, never()).save(any(User.class));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("testUploadImage_WhenThereIsAProblem_ThenReturnIOException")
    void testUploadImageWhenThereIsAProblemThenReturnIOException() throws IOException {
    }

}

my UserControllerTest:
package com.example.firsttask.controller;

import com.example.firsttask.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.firsttask.service.UserService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockMultipartFile;
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.example.firsttask.MotherObject.anyValidUserResponse;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyLong;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.content;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class UserControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    @Test
    void testSaveUserSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode201Created() throws Exception {
        when(userService.saveUser(any(UserDto.class))).thenReturn(anyValidUserResponse());

        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/v1/user/save")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(anyValidUserResponse()))
                )
                .andExpect(status().isCreated());
    }

    @Test
    void testGetUserByIdSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getUserById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidUserResponse()));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/user/1")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testGetAllUsersSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getAllUsers()).thenReturn(List.of(anyValidUserResponse()));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/user/all")
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testUploadImageSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("test", "test.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));

        when(userService.uploadImage(1L, multipartFile)).thenReturn("/api/v1/image/test.jpg");

        mockMvc.perform(multipart("/api/v1/image/test.jpg")
                        .file(multipartFile)
                        .param("id", "1")
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void testGetImageSuccessfullyReturnsHttpStatusCode200Ok() throws Exception {
        when(userService.getUserById(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(anyValidUserResponse()));
        MockMultipartFile multipartFile = new MockMultipartFile("image", "test.jpg", MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/image/test.jpg")
                        .param("id", "123")
                        .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE)
                )
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

}

please help me.
thanks
I wrote some test but they did not work.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
